# Last modification Date file system by creating a script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create an script or query to give me the last modification date of a file system. I have the below query and it works perfectly for an overwitted backup file. but I need to run it for *.bak that shows me the latest backup file modification date during many backup files:

--

```
if exists(select 1 from tempdb..sysobjects where name='##tmp')

drop table ##tmp

create table ##tmp(mdate varchar(8000))

insert ##tmp

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir g:\SQL_Backup\filename.bak' -- (I need the --last backup file name which the name keep changing every week)

set rowcount 5

delete from ##tmp

set rowcount 0

select top(1) substring(mdate,1,20) as 'Last modified date' from ##tmp
```

Comment: Are these the back up files your SQL Server is generating? If so, why not look in the `msdb.dbo.backupset` and `sys.databases` objects (like shown [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/04/sql-server-finding-last-backup-time-for-all-database/) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89278/get-last-full-backup-and-transaction-log-backup-for-each-database))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can run the PowerShell script and store in in sql server job.  It ran successfully.

```
$source = "\\00.0.00.00\your file location"
$filetype = "dif" (or "bak")

Get-ChildItem "$source\*" -Include "*.$filetype" | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1


$datetime=[datetime]::Today

if($datetime.DayOfWeek -match 'Monday'){

    Write-Host "YES"

}elseif($datetime.DayOfWeek -match 'Tuesday|Thursday|Saturday'){

    Write-Host "NO"

}else{
    
    Write-Host "YES"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with these views, so this really need a reality check before you really integrate it, but this may help:

```
select      
top 1       backupSetName = bs.name,
            backupFilePath = bf.physical_name, 
            backupFileLogicalName = bf.logical_name, 
            bs.backup_start_date,
            bs.backup_finish_date
from        msdb.dbo.backupfile bf
join        msdb.dbo.backupSet bs on bf.backup_set_id = bs.backup_set_id
where       right(bf.physical_name,4) = '.mdf'
order by    backup_finish_date desc;
```

"Backup Set" records the actual dates.  Since it is one-to-many with "Backup Files", it means that the '.mdf' and '.ldf' file dates are recorded together.  I just excluded the latter in the above output.

Comment: In other hand I want to create a job to check if latest backup(full and dif)  exist or not. and based on backup plan I can not look for a same file name everyday or every week.

Comment: your query works perfectly. I need to create a condition of this query: if backup exist do this else do that

Comment: @BDEZ, if you have further conditions, I would add another question.  But not before working through it and showing where you're stuck.

Comment: I just checked the database's mdf and ldf files, the haven't modified based on backups!!!